# Tableau elseif statement

Tags: tableau-api

Im currently having problems with this Tableau calculation. It seems to be adding together both fields worth of data when it should only be one if it is not null. Any ideas as to what is wrong?

```
IF ([Cost Type]="REVISED") THEN (IFNULL([Gis Labour],0)+IFNULL([Gis Im And E Labour],0)+IFNULL([Gis Im And E Non Labour],0)+IFNULL([OTHER_DIVISIONS_EXPENSE],0))

ELSEIF ([Cost Type]="ORIGINAL") THEN (IFNULL([Gis Labour],0)+IFNULL([Gis Im And E Labour],0)+IFNULL([Gis Im And E Non Labour],0)+IFNULL([OTHER_DIVISIONS_EXPENSE],0))

END
```

Comment: Can you share some more details on the results you are getting vs. what you expect?

Comment: We have a table in a database that has values in. If the option is revised and there is numbers in that record e.g 100, then this should be pulled through as it is not NULL. However, if it is a NULL value then the record with Original should be pulled through if this is not NULL.

Comment: For example - revised = 100 orginal = 120 - The result should just display 100. However at the moment it is combining the two together which is not what we want

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a difference between the two cases. Both add the same things.

Comment: That's correct. Both use the same fields its just that Revised should be selected if not null, then if it is, original should be used